# How to get from a Hyper-V 2008 R2 node with Powershell the IP address and Vlan ID

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scripting, powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I tried to take from the Hyper-V (Hyper-V 2012) node with this command the IP address:

> `Get-VM | select -ExpandProperty networkadapters | select vmname, ipaddress`

The thing is that i take as an output only the assigned Private IP addresses and not the Public IP addresses that some VMs have. Any idea why i have this problem?

Also is there any way to take in the same output and the Vlan ID that i have in my VM settings?
To get the Vlan from a specific VM i can do it with this

> `Get-VM 'Name of the VM' | Get-VMNetworkAdapterVlan | select AccessVlanId`

All of these things are on Hyper-V 2012 i want also this for Hyper-V 2008 R2. So some changes to the commands maybe required.

Comment: What PowerShell package are you using? Hyper-V 2008R2 doesn't come with any PowerShell modules and the SCVMM modules don't provide properties called `networkadapters`, `vmname`, and `ipaddress`.

Comment: @longneck You don't need SCVMM modules, and i didn't use SCVMM modules, but the built-in hyper-v modules. I am on a Hyper-V node. As i told i take output with IPs. The problem is _"The thing is that i take as an output only the assigned Private IP addresses and not the Public IP addresses that some VMs have. Any idea why i have this problem?"_

Comment: @longneck you are right, Hyper-V 2008R2 doesn't support this.. I edited my post. If you have now any idea, i would be glad to hear it.

Comment: Are the "Public IP's" actually assigned on the adapters in the VM, or are they assigned on a firewall and being NAT'ed?

Comment: @longneck No there are assigned on the network adapter inside the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Not having Hyper-V 2012 available for me to test with, I can at least address the PowerShell part of your question:

```
Get-VM | select -ExpandProperty networkadapters |
    Foreach-Object {
        $_ | AddMember -MemberType NoteProperty -Name VLAN -PassThru
            -Value ($_ | Get-VMNetworkAdapterVlan).AccessVlanID
    } | ft vmname, ipaddress, vlan
```

Answer (score 1):

I hate to just throw in links here, but you should look into James O'neils PowerShell library for Hyper-V 2008R2. Could save you some time.

[pshyperv.codeplex.com](http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/)